# Meaning of "public magnet" as an adjective for a school

Tags: word-usage

Can anyone elaborate on the meaning of "public magnet" as it qualifies a school? I found this in a Wikipedia article I was reading:

> Salinger attended public magnet Lowell High School in San Francico

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Salinger

Comment: Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Y'know... you could have moved your mouse to the Wikipedia search box, typed 'public magnet' and have had all the information you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wiki, magnet schools are public schools with specialized courses or curricula. So, a magnet school is just a type of public school. It was a bit of a tautology on the writer's part to say *public magnet Lowell High School* since *public* is already included in the magnet school definition.

Comment: Why would you downvote an answer that answers the question???

Comment: It was not my downvote, but some members of the community will downvote answers to questions that should not have been asked in the first place, i.e. those which are explicitly off-topic as detailed in the [help], such as those which can be answered by consulting a basic reference, like the wiki you cite but do not name or link.

Comment: @choster Thanks for the explanation. I don't think that makes any sense. If there's a problem with the question, take it up with the asker. I answered because I thought the OP had tried searching for just 'public magnet' and didn't get any results that made sense to him/her.